# Customisation on Tiny MCE editor

Tags: tinymce

We are currently experiencing two issues while revamping our editor screen. Firstly, we would like to integrate the chapter title section into the editor screen, as shown in the attached screenshots. The chapter title section should include a label and a placeholder, and it should also be scrollable. Secondly, we have noticed that the 3 dot menu is not closing when we click on the editor panel, but it does close when we click anywhere else on the screen except the editor panel.
[Making chapter title part of the editor screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaQ6D.png)
[Making chapter title scrollable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxg4k.png)
[Closing the 3 dot menu in case if writers clicks on the editor screen, while 3 dot menu is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wnrG.png)

#tinymce

We want to customise as explained above. It would be really helpful in case if you can let us know whether it's feasible. If feasible, kindly request your support on how to customise the editor panel, as explained in the above